# Recursive Sort Function in C++

Tags: c++

Is it even possible to do a recursive function without any loops?

Im researching recursive sort function without any looping. The task of the program is to sort the integers from biggest to smallest. This is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


void insert(vector<int> &v, int val) 
{   
    if(v.size() == 0 || v[v.size() +1] <= val) 
    {
        v.push_back(val);
        return;
    }
    
    int temp = v[v.size() -1];
    
    v.pop_back();
    
    insert(v, val);
    
    v.push_back(temp);      
    
}       

void recursiveSort(vector<int> &v)
{
    if(v.size() == 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    int val = v[v.size() -1];
    
    v.pop_back();
    recursiveSort(v);
    
    insert(v, val);
}   
        
    
    
int main() {


vector<int> v{8,2,3,6,5,8,7,9,1};



recursiveSort(v);

for(int x : v)
cout << x << " ";








    return 0;
    
}
```

The output is supposed to look like this:

```
Enter 4 integer values: 8 1 6 4
itr1:0 itr2:0 array:8,1,6,4
itr1:0 itr2:1 array:8,1,6,4
itr1:0 itr2:2 array:1,8,6,4
itr1:0 itr2:3 array:1,8,6,4
itr1:1 itr2:0 array:1,8,6,4
itr1:1 itr2:1 array:8,1,6,4
itr1:1 itr2:2 array:8,1,6,4
itr1:1 itr2:3 array:8,1,6,4
itr1:2 itr2:0 array:8,1,6,4
itr1:2 itr2:1 array:8,1,6,4
itr1:2 itr2:2 array:8,6,1,4
itr1:2 itr2:3 array:8,6,1,4
itr1:3 itr2:0 array:8,6,1,4
itr1:3 itr2:1 array:8,6,1,4
itr1:3 itr2:2 array:8,6,1,4
itr1:3 itr2:3 array:8,6,4,1
```

This is what the code would look like with looping:

```
f o r ( int i t r 1 = 0 ; i t r 1 < 4 ; i t r 1++ ) {
f o r ( int i t r 2 = 0 ; i t r 2 < 4 ; i t r 2++ ) {
c o u t <<” i t r 1 : ”<< i t r 1 <<” i t r 2 : ”<< i t r 2 << ” a r r a y : ” ;
c o u t <<a r r [0]<<” , ”<<a r r [1]<<” , ”<<a r r [2]<<” , ”<<a r r [3]<< e n d l ;
i f ( arr [ i t r 1 ] > arr [ i t r 2 ] ) {
int temp = a r r [ i t r 1 ] ;
arr [ i t r 1 ] = arr [ i t r 2 ] ;
a r r [ i t r 2 ] = temp ;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Sure this is possible, but it's a good idea to eliminate recursion, unless you gain some benefit from it. Simpler code would be one possible benefit, but in your scenario you do you'd increase complexity just for the sake of avoiding the use of loops; you'd basically just implement loops in a less efficient way by using recursion...

Comment: `v[v.size() +1]` is 2 elements out-of-bounds. Don't use `[]`, use `v.at()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.
Here is an example of [Selection Sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort/) without any loops using a recursive function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void recursiveSort(int arr[], int i, int j);
const int arrayLength = 10;


int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {3, 6, 1, 0, 7, 2, 5, 4, 6, 9};
    cout << "before sorting: " << endl;
    for (auto element : arr){
        cout << element << ' ';
    }
    
    recursiveSort(arr, 0, 1);
    
    cout << endl << "after sorting: " << endl;
    for (auto element : arr){
        cout << element << ' ';
    }
}

void recursiveSort(int arr[], int i, int j)
{
    if (j == arrayLength){
        return;
    }

    if (arr[i] < arr[j]){
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }

    recursiveSort(arr, i, j + 1);
    recursiveSort(arr, i + 1, i + 2);
}
```